# Sun Beams node. Where do the rays come from?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, volumetrics

Creating **Sun Rays** is always a struggle. 
Today, I am trying to create rays coming from below around silhouettes produced with transparent **PNGs** - reusing several tips I found on here.

And it seems that the rays are going down rather than up...

[image]

*In this setup, the light comes from an emission plane, above which are silhouettes.*

[image]

*The World Compositing setup.*

[image]

*The Volumetric environment.*

[image]

*Unfortunately, when I render the rays seem to come from above and mask part of the silhouettes! On this render, it is obvious that the emission is way below the silhouettes.*

**How do I make the rays come from the Emission object?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sun beams node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/sun_beams.html) works with normalized screen space coordinates, where (X0.5; Y0.5) is the Camera's midpoint.

[image]

Your current point (X0.7; Y1.1) is way out of the screen. Try something like (X0.5; Y0.25) - it will be lower part of the screen, where is light coming from.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that? In a panel, menu...?

Comment: "Sun beams node" is in your Compositor setup: left value is X coordinate, another one is Y

Comment: Oh - gotcha. Weird that these values don't have a name/label. Thanks

Comment: If you hover mouse cursor on these values, you'll get a tooltip "...bla, bla image width&height", but I agree about proper XY labels